# How to enable STOMP websocket with ActiveMQ and Spring

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I want to enable STOMP websockets in my tutorial application, so this is my configuration java file:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.spring.tut")
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableJms
public class Configuration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Configuration.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/apps");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/quotations");
    }
```

and my Controller:

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;

    @Autowired
public Controller(SimpMessagingTemplate template) {
    this.template = template;
}

@MessageMapping("/quotations")
@SendTo("/topic/greetings")
public String  handle(String quotations){
    return quotations;
}
```

}
I have this from https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/.
After module Run and after running stomp js client which looks like this:

```
var stomp = require('stomp');
var stomp_args = {
    port: 8091,
    host: 'localhost',
};

var client = new stomp.Stomp(stomp_args);


var headers = {
    destination: '/quotations',
    ack: 'client',
};

client.connect();


function message_callback(body, headers) {
    console.log('Message Callback Fired!');
    console.log('Body: ' + body);
}

client.on('connected', function() {
    client.subscribe(headers, message_callback);
    console.log('Connected');
}); 

client.on('message', function(message) {
    //console.log("HEADERS: " + sys.inspect(message.headers));
    //console.log("BODY: " + message.body);
    console.log("Got message: " + message.headers['message-id']);
    client.ack(message.headers['message-id']);
    messages++;
});

client.on('error', function(error_frame) {
    console.log(error_frame.body);
    client.disconnect();
});

setInterval(function(){


},1000);
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name. HTTP method names must be tokens
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:462) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:994) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_102]
```

and few seconds after this in console appear:

```
[MessageBroker-1] o.s.w.s.c.WebSocketMessageBrokerStats    : WebSocketSession[0 current WS(0)-HttpStream(0)-HttpPoll(0), 0 total, 0 closed abnormally (0 connect failure, 0 send limit, 0 transport error)], stompSubProtocol[processed CONNECT(0)-CONNECTED(0)-DISCONNECT(0)], stompBrokerRelay[null], inboundChannel[pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], outboundChannelpool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0], sockJsScheduler[pool size = 1, active threads = 1, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, I hope so its easy to make this code run.

I am using Spring-Boot with ActiveMQ with Tomcat 8.